# Converting ee.Image to numpy array in Earth Engine Python API takes too much time

Tags: google-earth-engine, numpy, matplotlib, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am using Earth Engine's Python API to convert `ee.Image()` to Python plots. I am currently using the `ee.sampleRectangle()` function to convert `ee.Image()` to a NumPy array and then using matplotlib's `imshow()` to generate the plot and save them as PNG.

What I have found is that even for the smallest of regions it takes atleast 1 sec for the conversion to **NumPy** arrays. I have lakhs of images I want to convert. Is there a better way to avoid the bottleneck I am facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sampleRectangle()` is not the ideal way to retrieve image pixels from Earth Engine, because they'll end up converted to JSON and back. Try using [`ee.Image.getDownloadURL()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl) — this can give you “NumPy binary format” data directly. (I'm not familiar with NumPy to tell you how exactly to use that, but I assume it'll suit your needs.)

That said, if your problem is the speed independent of region size, you might find it useful to modify your program to request multiple images in parallel rather than one at a time. (Not too many or your requests will be rejected, but it's entirely normal to do that at all — for example, the Earth Engine Code Editor requests many individual image tiles to make up the interactive map.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have implemented your suggestion, but unfortunately the getDownloadURL() method is taking more time than sampleRectangle for the same process.

Comment: @ShidharthRouth Sorry my idea didn't help. To get better ideas, you'll probably need to share a _specific_ program that demonstrates the slowness, rather than describing your problem abstractly. (Do that as an edit of the question — *not* in comments.)

Comment: I was able to overcome the problem with earth engine’s .map() function. Thank you so much for your time.